# "finally cyclic", definable over $(\mathbb{N},+)$

Tags: model-theory

Let $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ "finally cyclic" (I give the definition below).
Show, that $A$ is definable over $(\mathbb{N},+)$

Hello,

I have a question to this task.
I have to show, that the set $A$ is definable over $(\mathbb{N},+)$. So I have to give a formula $\varphi$ which describes the set. Or more specific, which describes every element of this set.

Definition:

$A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is "finally cyclic" iff $\exists n_0\exists m_0\forall n\geq n_0(n\in A\Leftrightarrow n+m_0\in A)$.

The problem of this task is, that I have to describe every element of this set.
For example:

$A=\{1,7,29,30,33,35,100,101,102,103,104, ...\}$ is finally cyclic, because for $n_0=100$ exists $m_0=1$ and every number which is greater than 100 is an element of $A$.

To give the part of the formula, which describes the numbers greater than 100 is no problem.
But what is with the numbers 1, 7, 29, 30, 33, 35?

Well, it is clear, that the amount of "non-cyclic-numbers" is finite. So you can just write them down one by one, with variables.
Like $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5$ and $v_6$. Or $v_1, ..., v_i$ in general.
With $v_1=1, ..., v_6=35$

Another problem is to show, that the formula really describes a set.
That every element is just once in the set.

Also I am not sure, how a formula can describe a set in generall.
When I want to define the random set $B=\{0,1\}$ over $(\mathbb{N},+,\cdot)$.

Is it enough to describe those two numbers, and does this make the formula already a "set", when it describes a list of numbers (or what so ever)?

Can someone help me with my questions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Supposing you can do the "final" part, you do can something like $x=n_0 \lor x = n_1 \lor \cdots \lor x = n_k \lor (x> 100 \land \phi(x))$, where $\phi$ defines the final part

Comment: @James Of course this has to be done using only addition. Not that that's hard, for example $x>100$ iis equivalent to $\exists n\, x = 100+n$.

Comment: What you write is too unclear. Are you allowed to use parameters in your definitions?  Also, I have no idea what you mean by the formula describing a set. And the bit about each element being just once is meaningless.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich We also need a non-zero constant.

Comment: @James No, $\leq$ is definable by $\exists z\, x+z = y$, and $0$ is clearly definable, so $1$ is definable by $\forall y\, (0\leq y \land y\leq x) \rightarrow (y = 0 \lor y = x)$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman So it is, thanks.

Comment: @AlexKruckman (and a clause stating that $0\ne x$)

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Yes, thanks. Somehow I find it impossible to write down explicit first-order formulas on this site without making errors like this...

Comment: My main problem is, that I do not really know, how I can describe that certain variables are elements from $A$. My try looks like this $\varphi\equiv v_1,..., v_n(v_i=n_0\wedge \forall x\geq n_0(x+d=m))$ For explaination: My firststep is to note the finite amount of "non-cyclic-numbers" by $v_1,..., v_n$ what follows is that under these finite numbers one $v_i$ exists (which is also greater than the others, so v_i>v_k for every k\in\{1,...,n\}\setminus\{i\}$ but I dont think it is necessary to note this.) that every other element is from the form x+m. Maybe I need to do the last part recursive

Comment: What you wrote is not even a formula.

Comment: Yes, I know. It was more a try how it could end up. The first part $v_1,...,v_n$ is not correct. But I do not know how to write it down, that it becomes a formula...

Answer (score 1):

I sum up partial answers in the comments to a full answer.

$x\le y$ is definable by $\exists z\ x+z=y$

$x=0$ is definable by $\forall y\ x\le y$

$x=1$ is definable by $0<x\wedge\neg\exists y\ 0<y<x$

$x=m$ for any natural number $m$ is definable.

Therefore, every finite set is definable.

The term $nx$ is definable by $x+\dots(n$ times$)\dots+x$

The range of an arithmetic progression is a definable set: $\exists y\  \ m+ny=x$

Finally, note that definable sets are closed under boolean operations and obtain that any *finally cyclic sets* is definable.